# Select statement with column contains '%'

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to select names from a table where the 'name'  column contains '%' anywhere in the value. For example, I want to retrieve the name 'Approval for 20 % discount for parts'.

```
SELECT NAME FROM TABLE WHERE NAME ... ?
```

Comment: So what happened when you did so? Any error? Unexpected output? Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `like` with `escape`.  The default is a backslash in some databases (but not in Oracle), so:

```
select name
from table
where name like '%\%%' ESCAPE '\'
```

This is standard, and works in most databases.  The Oracle documentation is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm).

Of course, you could also use `instr()`:

```
where instr(name, '%') > 0
```

Comment: From the linked documentation, "If esc_char is not specified, then there is **no default** escape character." [emphasis added.]

Comment: @ShannonSeverance . . . Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using `replace` with an empty string and checking to see if the difference in length of the original string and modified string is > 0.

```
select name 
from table 
where length(name) - length(replace(name,'%','')) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Make life easy on yourselves and just use REGEXP_LIKE( )!

```
SQL> with tbl(name) as (
      select 'ABC' from dual
      union
      select 'E%FS' from dual
    )
    select name
    from tbl
    where regexp_like(name, '%');

NAME
----
E%FS

SQL>
```

Answer (score -1):

I read the documentation mentioned by Gordon.  The relevent sentence is:

`An underscore (_) in the pattern matches exactly one character (as opposed to one byte in a multibyte character set) in the value`

Here was my test:

```
select c 
from (
select 'a%be' c
from dual) d
where c like '_%'
```

The value `a%be` was returned.

While the suggestions of using `instr()` or `length` in the other two answers will lead to the correct answer, they will do so slowly.  Filtering on function results simply take longer than filtering on fields.

Comment: `c like '_%'` matches all strings of length 1 or greater, not just ones containing `%`.